Why do we need more security than the private key distribution?
I'm new to cryptography and have question about private key distribution. If we are able to send private keys to the encoder, then it means that we are able to send private keys to someone, which others
can not know it. So why isn't this enough for secure communication?
If we can send a key to just one person and others cannot see it, then why should I think about more security?

Welcome to Cryptography. What is the reason for CAPITALS and 0? What if the key is compromised? How soon can you send a new one? It is not about security it is about convenience.

We send the answer of the factorization factor through the private key. So what if it is eveasdropped? I mean if the public key is not enough so the private is also not enough. Am I right?

It's very hard to tell what you are asking. I think you lack the basic understanding about cryptography. In this case it is probably better to read into it rather than starting  to ask questions as you lack the required terminology. Normally we do not directly send private keys to persons, we use public key distribution (PKI). The private key of the key pair is usually kept under control of the receiver (assuming encryption).

Why do you send the factorization? In which protocol did you see that? RSA-KEM, DHKE, etc are long secure enough with correct parameters against classical adversaries to protect your key encapsulation or key establishment.

@MaartenBodewes yes. so give a simple reference to learn more about the basics. Thanks


If we can send a key to just one person and others cannot see it, then why should I think about more security?

Indeed, if we can safely distribute a private key, than we do not need more security (in the sense of confidentiality) than given by the mean used for that distribution. But we do not need to distribute private keys in the first place, thus we may have no such mean!
In cryptography, unless otherwise stated, a private key is the secret half of a public/private key pair. If not (that is, with symmetric cryptography), it's called a secret key. In the following I assume the question is really about private key.
In the most desirable and quite common setup, a private key is never distributed: the key pair is generated on a device (computer, mobile phone, smart card, Yubikey...), by the device, for the device or a user thereof. The private key is expected to never leave the device. That gives the best possible security (in the sense of confidentiality). Often, the next stage after generation is using the device to generate a Certificate Signing Request of (and embedding the) public key, to a certification authority. It's the public key or certificate that is distributed, and they need not be secret (only their integrity and origin matters).
When we want to distribute a private key (e.g. for backup purpose for more security in the sense of availability, or/and if the user has multiple devices and wants to use the same key pair on several), then indeed we want the utmost possible security (in the sense of confidentiality) for that distribution. And then even if that distribution mean works fine, we might want to use something else for other kind of data, because that distribution mean might obtain it's high security at the expense of being inconvenient or/and slow or/and expensive (e.g. physical transport by a trusted messenger).
But secure transport of secrets is hard and uncertain, and why distributing the private key to another device is often (and best) replaced by generating another key pair on that other device, and following whatever procedure is necessary to use that key pair.

In cryptography, most of the times we care about public key cryptography. Having a private key distribution is something unachievable in most cases. Indeed, as you said, if we had private key distribution (had a "secret" channel that only the 2 of us could access it) then we wouldn't need most of the cryptography.
There are protocols that help 2 people that can't communicate in secret, to be able to come with a common secret, just by talking loudly (in public). An example of such protocol is the Diffie-Hellman Key-Exchange.
However, I believe that in order to understand more clear about public key cryptography, i.e., 2 people want to communicate secretly but do not have a common key, a nice visualization as the following can help:
Imagine you have a box and a lock (those small ones that have an arc on top and can be unlocked from the bottom). Only you have the key that opens the lock.
Now, your friend Bob tells you publicly that he wants to tell you something in private.

You send to him by mail your box and your lock both opened.
Bob, will put his message inside and lock the box with the lock. Afterwards, he will ship it back to you.
Now, since you have the key that opens the lock, you can unlock it and open the box to read his letter.

You can see that no one could actually open the lock when it was shipped back to you. Not even Bob could, but he didn't need to in order to send you something, since you shipped him your box/lock opened.
What Bob did was simply close the box and lock it with your lock (and this can happen without possession of a key).

You never, never, ever send a private key. A private key should be generated by your device. And then it should stay on your device forever and never leave it.
You use the private key to create as many public keys as you like, and you distribute them as far as you can. Completely in the open.
The idea is that some operations need the private key, and only you a nobody else can perform these operations. On the other hand, anybody can perform operations using the public key.
For example, anyone with a copy of your public key can encrypt a message that only you as the owner of the private key can decrypt and read.

"Never" is a big word. I agree this answer is basically correct. There are sometimes reasons to e.g. perform private key operations on a separate device, e.g. for remote signing where the security of the remote device is higher than the local device (server with HSM vs mobile phone). I'd say that at least the usage of the private key is still under control of the user though. If it weren't, signing would be meaningless.
